# Android shared app constants best practice

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, constants, sharedpreferences

I wonder which is the best practice to manage shared constants through the app.
The problem is to use them with consistent naming both in View and ViewModel and in XML resource files and in SharedPreferences.

For example let's start from preferences.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class PreferencesAspectFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

  override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_aspect, rootKey)
  }
}
```

So, we have in preferences_aspect.xml:

```
<ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="by_label"
        app:entries="@array/preferences_aspect_sort_order_entries"
        app:entryValues="@array/preferences_aspect_sort_order_values"
        app:key="aspect.sort_order"
        app:title="@string/preferences_aspect_sort_order"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
```

And our keys are stored in arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="preferences_aspect_sort_order_values">
        <item>by_label</item>
        <item>by_label_desc</item>
        <item>by_created</item>
        <item>by_created_desc</item>
</string-array>
```

If I need to get the stored preference value inside the app I need to write:

```
val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext())
val preferencesSort = sharedPreferences.getString("aspect.sort_order", "")
```

And if I want to use it:

```
when(preferencesSort){
  "by_label" -> sortByLabel()
  "by_label_desc" -> sortByLabelDesc()
  "by_created" -> sortByCreated()
  "by_created_desc" -> sortByCreatedDesc()
  else -> sortByLabel()
}
```

And so on. I'm using a lot of strings:

```
"aspect.sort_order" "by_label" "by_label_desc" "by_created" "by_created_desc"
```

that are prone to typos, while I'd like to use constants. Or, at least, strings defined in one single point.

I could create an XML file keys.xml like this:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">
    <string name="key.sort.by_label" translatable="false">
        <xliff:g id="key.sort.by_label">sort.by_label</xliff:g>
    </string>
    <string name="key.sort.by_label_desc" translatable="false">
        <xliff:g id="key.sort.by_label_desc">sort.by_label_desc</xliff:g>
    </string>
</resources>
```

And than use it in other XML files:

```
<string-array name="preferences_aspect_sort_order_values">
        <item>@string/key.sort.by_label</item>
        <item>@string/key.sort.by_label_desc</item>
...
```

If I need these constants in a View I can use:

```
getString(R.string.key_sort_by_label)
```

I don't like this solution at all, it is not clean, nor terse and a little confusing.
Moreover in a ViewModel I'd need to refere to the context to use getString and is not a good idea.

So what could be the best way to avoid all these strings to name my constants?

Thank you very much

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed for being opinion-based, so you might want to rephrase. I use your solution, but create extension functions for retrieving the preference values using just the Int resource ids.  There's no other way to avoid copy-pasting String keys used in the Preference XML to the Kotlin code. But you don't need to put SharedPreferences into ViewModels. A cached in-memory copy is kept once the app first reads them, so it's trivial to retrieve them on demand every time you need to read or write the values. Don't need to use a ViewModel to keep them in memory.

Comment: Thanks Tenfour04! How can I read from the cached one copy of SharedPreferences from the ViewModel?

Comment: It’s done automatically after the first time you access a particular preferences file. Nothing special you need to do.